# Share Calendar with two Google accounts

Tags: google-calendar, google-account, synchronization

I have two Google accounts, say `Account1` and `Account2`. I use and maintain a single calendar from `Account1`. Each time I'm in `Account2` and need to add a calendar event, I log out of `Account2` then into `Account1` and finally add the event to the calendar.

Is there a better way? One option would be to maintain separate calendars for each account but more interesting would be to set `Account2` to use (and be able to view, edit, etc) the calendar from `Account1`...I'd be fine with disabling the calendar for `Account2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can share your main calendar from Account1 with Account2.

Just go to the settings (gear, upper right) in Account1, choose Calendars and enter "Share this calendar" right of your main-calendar. Then you can enter the e-mail address of Account2 and choose "Make changes and Manage sharing" and you'll get a notification-mail in Account2 to add that calendar. Now you can manage the complete calendar for Account1 while being logged-in as Account2.

[image]

Please note that when adding events, your main calendar of Account2 is checked by default. If you only want Account1s calendar visible you can press the pull-down next to Account1-calendar and choose "Display only this calendar". Any new events will be for Account1 as default.

[image]

Comment: Nice detail about hiding the (unused) calendar for `Account2`. This means when you create a new calendar event (while logged into `Account2`), the calendar from `Account1` is selected by default and you don't accidentally leave `Account2` selected. Good answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to `calendar.google.com`.
2. From the wheel icon from the top right select `Settings`.
3. Under the `Calendar` tab find the calendar you want to share and in
   the right you have the option `Share this calendar`.
4. Under `Share with specific people` add your other email address and
   select the permission settings you want. Most likely in your case
   `Make changes to events`.
5. Save and Done.